# PythonのloggingでERRORを出力する方法

Tags: python, logging

`import logging`でlevelをDEBUGにしているのですが、
自分で仕込んだエラー
`logging.debug('hogehoge')`
しか拾ってくれず、例えば、Pythonの方で発生した
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp932' codec can't encode character '\u202c' in position 913: illegal multibyte sequence`
のようなものは拾ってくれません。
どのようにすべきでしょうか。

**実行環境**

- Windows 10
- Python 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これらの記事のように、例外が起きそうな処理を`try: except:`で囲んで、発生した例外情報を元に自分で出力することになります。
[【Python】logging でStackTrace(スタックトレース)をログ出力する方法 | 備忘録](https://ryoz001.com/1424.html)

> ```
> try:
>     【例外が発生しそうな処理】
> except Exception as e:
>     logging.error(【任意のメッセージ】, exc_info=True)
> ```

[Print exception with stack trace to file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31636884/9014308)
回答の以下の部分`1/0`で0除算の例外になる。

> ```
> import logging
> from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
> import traceback
>
> logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
> logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
> handler = RotatingFileHandler("log.txt", maxBytes=10000, backupCount=5)
> formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
> handler.setFormatter(formatter)
> logger.addHandler(handler)
> try:
>     1/0 
> except Exception as e:
>     logger.error(str(e))
>     logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
> ```